# Generating EPOLLRDHUP event on tcp socket

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp, epoll

How do I trigger an EPOLLRDHUP event on my tcp socket using the other thread programatically,

I have added the epoll instance with EPOLLRDHUP event and tried to generate the event, but it modifies the event on that FD , do not trigger it,

I want my first thread which is continuously waiting for event with epoll_wait(), should receive the event from EPOLLRDHUP, as soon as the other thread triggers it, I am not able to get how to trigger that event, I tried using write system call in another thread but that also do not trigger the event on socket FD I guess, poll should come out of blocking loop is my requirement, Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate epoll events on same file descriptor from another thread, EPOLLRDHUP would be generated based on something happening at the other end of the TCP connection.

If you have 1 thread waiting on `epoll_wait()` and you want to wake that thread up from another thread, you should create a [pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)(), have your epoll_wait wait for read events on the reading side of the pipe in addition to any TCP sockets. When you want to wake up your thread, you write a byte on the writing side of the pipe.

(an [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) could be used instead of the pipe to achieve the same too)